# Loop through leaf in a tuple structure

Tags: scala, types, functional-programming, purely-functional

Let say I have a function `fn` that accept a tuple in the following form:

```
fn(
 "a" -> (
   "b" -> "k",
   "c" -> 293,
   "d" ->(
     "e" -> Seq("i", "j"),
     "f" -> Seq(1, 2)
     )
   ),
 "g" -> (
   "h" -> true
  )
)
```

I don't know how I could implement `fn` to be able to loop through each leaf (being "b", "c", "e", "f" and finally "h") knowing each time the leaf own parents.

Shapeless seems to be a solution, even if I don't know how to implement it.

Note: A vanilla scala approach is preferred (if it's possible).
Note: I know I have a `Tuple2(String, T)`, where T can either be another Tuple(String, T), a string, a number, a boolean, or a Seq[V].
Note: Seq[V] where V can either be a string, a number or a boolean.

Comment: What do you mean by the leaf knowing its parents?

Comment: Also, this is in the category of things that it's entirely possible to do without Shapeless (you don't need the macro-powered generic machinery, etc.), but it would be much, much more verbose.

Comment: If types are known at compile-time, you can use macro to match types and generate sequence of leafs. If they aren't, you can use pattern matching.

Comment: It means that when I iterate over a leaf (let say I am on "e"), I know that "b" has "d" and "a" as a parent, that's what I meant by "leaf knowing its parents"

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what you mean by "knowing each time the leaf own parents", but you should be able to tweak this to do what you need:

```
  def traverseLeaves(p: Product)(visitor: (String,Any) => Unit):Unit = p match { 
    case (parent:String, child:Seq[_]) => visitor(parent, child)
    case (_:String, child: Product) => traverseLeaves(child)(visitor)
    case (parent:String, child) => visitor(parent, child)
    case _ => p.productIterator.foreach { 
      case child:Product => traverseLeaves(child)(visitor)
      case _ => ???
    }
  }
```

Note, this will throw an exception if it finds a more-than-two-element tuple anywhere, containing anything other other than tuples, because it was not clear from your question what you intend to do in that situation. If you want to handle it differently, change the `???` to the logic that will handle that case.